# DevOps run npm install if local node_modules folder is missing

Tags: node.js, powershell, azure-devops

I am using DevOps build definition to bundle an AngularJs app. Is there a way to check if the local node_modules exists and if it doesn't exist run the npm install command before the bundling process takes place?

Comment: Isn't npm optimized to do just this?  An `npm install` is just going to verify your packages/versions in npm install, but as long as everything already matches it won't actually download anything.

Comment: Yes, the npm installs step handles this thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a script task to check if the folder exists and then set a variable. For the npm task, you need to set the condition to run. Please refer to following content.

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'if [ -d "node_modules" ]; then
            echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=FOLDEREXISTS]true"
      fi'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    condition: eq(variables.FOLDEREXISTS, 'true')
```